# Underscores in type bounds on type constructors

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds, type-constructor

Can someone explain why the following doesn't compile? I want that `BB[A]` is also a `List[A]`. The method body only enforces this view.

```
scala> def x[A, BB[_] <: List[_]](p: BB[A]) {p: List[A]}
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : BB[A]
 required: List[A]

       def x[A, BB[_] <: List[_]](p: BB[A]) {p: List[A]}
                                             ^
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use the variable name `p` two times? First as a `BB[A]` and then as `List[A]`? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to name the _ parameter.

```
scala> def x[A, BB[X] <: List[X]](p: BB[A]) {p: List[A]}
```

works.

Comment: indeed, the definition `BB[_] <: List[_]` means something else: `BB[x] <: List[T forSome {type T}]`, the `_` only defines an anonymous higher-order type parameter when defining a type parameter list. In all other positions, `_` introduces an anonymous existential type (like a Java wildcard). Thus, in `List[_]`, where the `_` is used as a type argument (it's not defining a new type parameter list for `List` of course), it becomes an existential type. Think of it another way: if you had multiple anonymous type parameters (which are all called `_`, how would you refer to them individually?)

Comment: I find it helps readability to use a lowercase "name" for type placeholders like this. Wouldn't go so far as to call it idiomatic, but it's certainly a trend I've seen used by others.

Comment: Also, comparing the level of types and values, it is quite unfortunate that the type-level underscore behaves differently from the value-level underscore. At the value level, `_ + _` indeed stands for `(x, y) => x + y`, a function. As hinted at in my other comment, the type-level underscore is context-sensitive, and it never introduces a type-level function. It's either an anonymous type parameter definition or an anonymous existential. Neither of these have value-level equivalents.