# Why does ((_: Int, _: Int) => _ / _) not compile when ((_: Int) / (_: Int)) does?

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

I am learning Scala and have a very basic question. Consider the following two expressions using the placeholder syntax -

```
// Syntax A  
val fnA = (_: Int, _: Int) => _ / _

// Syntax B
val fnB = (_: Int) / (_: Int)
```

and their attempted applications -

```
// Syntax A
fnA(33, 3)

// Syntax B
fnB(33, 3)
```

Out of these two, only B and App(B) are valid syntax and I am not sure why. If the compiler is able to infer the arguments (and the order to apply them in) in `fnB` why is it not able to do it for `fnA`? I am basing my question on the premise that `fnB` is a shorthand for `fnA` and I am pretty certain there's a flaw in that reasoning. I am just not sure what the flaw is.

Comment: If `val fnA = (_: Int, _: Int) => _ / _` would be the valid syntax, then it would a function which ignores is arguments and then return another function. **B** is actually a shorthand of `(x: Int, Y: Int): Int => x / y`. BTW, the placeholder syntax is not as a good idea as you may think, I would recommend you to do not use it too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of underscores on the left of arrow `=>`

```
(_: Int, _: Int) => ...
```

are **different** from the meaning of underscores around the infix operator `/`

```
(_: Int) / (_: Int)
```

The former mean something like

> "We are defining a function that takes two arguments, however
>   we will not use these arguments in the body of the function"

whilst the latter is a shorthand for defining a function of two arguments

```
(x: Int, y: Int) => x / y
```

For example,

```
(_: Int, _: Int) => (_: Int) / (_: Int)
```

desugars to something like

```
(a: Int, b: Int) => ((x: Int, y: Int) => x / y)
```

where we see arguments `a` and `b` are not used in the body which happens to be yet another function `((x: Int, y: Int) => x / y)`.

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001132/5205022) documents the two meanings as

```
_ + _             // Anonymous function placeholder parameter
_ => 5            // Discarded parameter
```

---

As a side-note, consider a somewhat analogous situation at the typelevel involving type constructors and their bounds where the meaning of underscore depends on the context

```
CC[_] <: Iterable[_]
```

Personally, my mind tricks me to think it is equivalent to

```
CC[x] <: Iterable[x]
```

however that is not the case, and the meaning of the underscore on the left of `<:` is **different** from the meaning on the right

```
CC[x] <: Iterable[y] forSome {type y}
```

Note how `x` does not appear in `Iterable[y] forSome {type y}`. Adrian documents this under [Common Pitfalls](http://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/#common_pitfalls):

> ...perhaps surprisingly, `CC[_] <: Traversable[_]` is not equivalent to
>   `CC[X] <: Traversable[X]`. The former expands to `CC[X] <: Traversable[T] forSome {type T}`, where `T` is existentially bound and thus unrelated to
>   `X`.

and in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492934/scala-type-bounds-on-type-constructor/6493098#comment7710891_6493098) to [type bounds on type constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492934/5205022)

> comparing the level of types and values, it is quite unfortunate that
>   the type-level underscore behaves differently from the value-level
>   underscore. At the value level, `_ + _` indeed stands for `(x, y) => x + y`, a function. As hinted at in my other comment, the type-level
>   underscore is context-sensitive, and it never introduces a type-level
>   function. It's either an anonymous type parameter definition or an
>   anonymous existential. Neither of these have value-level equivalents.

Hence we should be careful to interpret the meaning of the underscore within its context.